# Add a gradient to a shape/line

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to add a gradient to a line shape in Excel using VBA. This feature is available in the `Line Color` section under the `Format Shape` option. Despite this feature existing under the `Format Shape` option, I am unable to reproduce the functionality in VBA. My code is:

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Straight Connector 4")
    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(193, 193, 193)
    .Line.Transparency = 0.25
    .Line.Visible = msoTrue
    .Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 24
    .Line.BackColor.SchemeColor = 34
    .Line.GradientStops.Insert RGB(255, 0, 0), 0.25 ' Creates error
    .Line.Gradient.ColorStops.Add (1) ' Creates error
End With
```

I know you can easily add a gradient to the shape fill but all search results are returning nothing when wanting to add a gradient to a shape line. Any ideas are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible. You can set a gradient for a shape's fill through VBA, but you can't do it for a line.
You can either create a thin shape with gradient fill and no border, or you will have to use something outside VBA. (Eg. VB.NET + OpenXLM SDK.)