# Coloring a graph with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of data point in excel in the following format:

```
2016  3
2017  4
2018  5
```

Each of the cell (in the right colomn) is coloured in different colour. 
For example:

```
2016 3(red)
2017 4(blue)
2018 5(blue)
```

I am building a line graph and want each of the dot in the line and connecting line to have the color of the filled cell.

I have found some code for bar charts, but it doesn't work with line charts. Any help would be appreciated. (Below is the code for barchart)

```
Sub SetChartColorsFromDataCells()

If TypeName(Selection) <> "ChartArea" Then
    MsgBox "??????? ???????? ?????????!"
    Exit Sub
End If
Set c = ActiveChart
For j = 1 To c.SeriesCollection.Count
    f = c.SeriesCollection(j).Formula
    m = Split(f, ",")
    Set r = Range(m(2))

    For i = 1 To r.Cells.Count
        c.SeriesCollection(j).Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = _
            r.Cells(i).Interior.Color
    Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `c.SeriesCollection(j).Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB` is trying to `Fill` the interior of a `Point`.  However, the `Point` in question is a line - rather than a rectangle, as it would be in a Bar chart - so it doesn't *have* an interior.  Use `Point.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB` for that.

The Marker (i.e. the "dot in each line") is controlled by `Point.MarkerForegroundColor` (the outline) and `Point.MarkerBackgroundColor` (the interior)

Put it all together, and you get this:

```
For i = 1 To r.Cells.Count
    With c.SeriesCollection(j).Points(i)
        .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = r.Cells(i).Interior.Color
        .MarkerForegroundColor = r.Cells(i).Interior.Color
        .MarkerBackgroundColor = r.Cells(i).Interior.Color
    End With
Next I
```

Unfortunately, while you *can* you VBA to apply a Gradient to a shape, you **can't** (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621765/add-a-gradient-to-a-shape-line)) use it to apply a Gradient to a Line - otherwise, you could have a smooth transition between colours for each point...